# Customize text before bring print through log4j

Tags: java, spring, log4j, slf4j

I'm working on a pretty big code base. there are a lot of logs getting printed. I'm trying to find away to modify all the existing logs to mask out some some text that is not suppose to be printed. I know I can just find all these logs and modify the String but this is pretty much impossible due to code size, and also for future as well incase someone print the log that they are not suppose to.

What I have tried so far is making a custom logger class that return a modified version of `Logger` interface (the interface that `Logger.getLogger()` returns) to process the String before printing. This works fine but this means I will have to replace all the instances of `Logger.getLogger()` with my new custom class, but again due to code size, this is not something I can do.

So is there away to have `Logger.getLogger()` to return my own implmentation of Logger interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to make `Logger.getLogger()` to return the customized implementation of Logger interface.
We can however extends `PatternLayout` class which log4j uses to format logs.
This class gives us access to a method call `format` which takes in `LoggingEvent` as parameter. we can override this method and modify the `LoggingEvent` which contains the log that gets printed.